# Using Magick.NET with C#

Tags: c#, imagemagick, magick.net

I am trying to implement a functionality using Magick.NET in C#.

Previously I was using:-

```
// Convert to a png.
Process p = new Process();

p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.2.8-Q16\convert.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-scale 60% \"" + svg + "\" \"" + png + "\"";
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

p.Start();

p.WaitForExit();

TransmitFile(context, png);
```

I want to move away from having to store convert.exe on the server.....Now I want to use something that will be in code and doesn't need to reference an executable file on the server:-

```
// Pseudo-code:-
MagickImage img = new MagicImage();
Image.Add(svg);
Image.Format = MagickFormat.png;
Image.Scale = 60%;
```

But I cannot find enough documentation to implement the same functionality that I was using before. Is there a place with appropriate documentations? I have googled quite a bit, without success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some examples of how to use Magick.NET available [here](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/tree/master/docs#documentation).

An example of how to convert one image to another image can be found [here](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/master/docs/ConvertImage.md#convert-image). But there is no example for `-scale 60%`.

Most options from the command line have the same name in the MagickImage class. Your command `convert input.svg -scale 60% output.png` translates to this:

```cs
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage("input.svg"))
{
  image.Scale(new Percentage(60));
  image.Write("output.png");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am getting a couple of errors though:-

using - 'ImageMagickObject.MagickImage': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable' ............

'ImageMagickObject.MagickImage' does not contain a definition for 'Write' and no extension method 'Write' accepting a first argument of type 'ImageMagickObject.MagickImage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?............


The type or namespace name 'Percentage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?.........

Comment: I installed Magic.NET x64.dll and Core.dll and wrapper-x64.dll in Visual Studio

Comment: It looks like you are using some other library that has a class called MagickImage. The namespace of the MagickImage class is ImageMagick not ImageMagickOjbect

Comment: you are right, I have both ImageMagick and ImageMagickObject referenced at the namespace. But after removing the latter, now MagickImage has an issue - the type or namespace 'MagickImage' could not be found (missing reference??)

Comment: You should add a 'using' for ImageMagick.

Comment: I am using ImageMagick now, but in the statement  MagickImage image = new MagickImage()... I am getting the reference error.... do I have to add the assembly to the web.config :
<system.web><compilation><assemblies><addassembly="Magick.NET-x64"/></assemblies></compilation></system.web>

Comment: I looked in the object browser and my imageMagick namespace doesn't have a "magickImage" in it.

Comment: Found the solution, seems like the way I installed Magick.NET thru NuGet on my VS2012 was the issue... or maybe the version installed. I went to Magick.NET website and downloaded the dll manually and referenced it in my project and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of scale, how do I compress the image? Can you please share.

Comment: Seems like your link is not working anymore... Could you update it please?